# need help building a query to detect duplicates on multiple columns

Tags: select, duplication, mariadb-10.5

I have the following table

```sql
create table catalog_product_entity_varchar
(
    value_id     int auto_increment comment 'Value ID'
        primary key,
    attribute_id smallint unsigned default 0 not null comment 'Attribute ID',
    store_id     smallint unsigned default 0 not null comment 'Store ID',
    entity_id    int unsigned      default 0 not null comment 'Entity ID',
    value        varchar(255)                null comment 'Value',  
)
```

I want to find all entity_ids where `attribute_id = 86` for the same `store_id` where the `value` is the same.

For example for the columns `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`

`86, 1, 1, mypath`

is duplicate with

`86, 1, 2, mypath`

but is not duplicate with

`86, 2, 1, mypath`

The result would be `entity_id`, `store_id`, `value`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create a https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5 with some sample data, post back the url and the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with grouping on your `store_id` and `value` in a **CTE** or **subquery** to get the dupes and then re-joining the dupes to your  `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table like so:

```
WITH CTE_Dupes AS
(
     SELECT store_id, value
     FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
     WHERE attribute_id = 86
     GROUP BY store_id, value
     HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
)

SELECT C.entity_id, C.store_id, C.value
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar C
INNER JOIN CTE_Dupes D
    ON C.store_id = D.store_id
    AND C.value = D.value
WHERE C.attribute_id = 86
```